# Setting initialising storyboard with a UISwitch

Tags: swift, viewcontroller, uiswitch

I'm struggling to work out how to set the initialising view controller programatically within a view controller's file. I understand how to do it in the appdelegate.swift, but I need it done in a view controller using a `UISwitch`       So if it is set on, it change the initialising view controller, and if it isn't, it just doesn't do anything. Any idea how I would go about doing this?

```
if self.`switch`.on {


} else {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

take outlet to UISwitch in viewController then in your viewDidLoad() add the following code:

```
if uiSwitch.on {
// if swith is on
 let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerIdentifier") as? ViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
} else {
 // if switch is off
}
```

Comment: I want to use it outside of the viewDidLoad() when another statement is true, and then check the UISwitch, how would that work?

Comment: you can use it in viewWillAppear()

Comment: Is it possible to use it outside of any override func ?

Comment: yes but you will also need to call that function from the viewcontroller lifecycle methods

Comment: When I use this code, nothing happens, no errors, nothing changes. I'm also trying to use this in a Button Action

Comment: did you change your storyboard identifier of viewController with this ("ViewControllerIdentifier") ?

Comment: This is my code, and it isn't changing when I run the app again:     @IBAction func loginAction(sender: AnyObject) {

                        if self.`switch`.on {
                            let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeViewController") as? HomeViewController
                            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
                            
                        } else {
                            
                        }
}

Comment: have you taken outlet for UISwitch in viewcontroller?

Comment: Yes, it is linked with the view controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99005/discussion-between-ajinkya-patil-and-maxkrissigo).